# Fragment layout on the top of MainActivty layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I decided to implement navigation drawer in my app. I did it step by step. When I run emulator app displays the main screen. However, when i click on the menu item, the "fragment_weather.xml" layout displays on the top "content_main.xml". When I click I want to make content_main invisible and fragment_weather visible. 
    So far it looks like that:

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView gminaImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gminaImageView);
        ImageView weatherImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.weatherImageView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Integer announcementId = intent.getIntExtra("announcementId", 0);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("announcementId", announcementId);
        AnnouncementFragment announcementFragment = new AnnouncementFragment();
        announcementFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        weatherImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                WeatherFragment fragment = new WeatherFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.replacableConstraintLayout, fragment);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        gminaImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });


        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_gmina) {
            AnnouncementListFragment listFragment = new AnnouncementListFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.replacableConstraintLayout, listFragment).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_restauracja) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sklep) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_weather) {

            WeatherFragment weatherFragment = new WeatherFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.replacableConstraintLayout, weatherFragment).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_policja) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_onas) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

content_main.xml

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/replacableConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_width="160sp"
        android:layout_height="160sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gminaImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gmina" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/gminaImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/shopImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/restauracja"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="144dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shopImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sklep" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weatherImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/policeImageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gminaTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.222"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pogoda" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/policeImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/weatherImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/aboutUsImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/restaurantTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.197"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/police" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutUsImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/policeImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shopTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.197"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/onas" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Wybierz interesującą Cię kategorię ogłoszenia"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurantTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Restauracja"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/restaurantImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/restaurantImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutUsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="O nas"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/aboutUsImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/aboutUsImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aboutUsImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/policeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Policja"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/policeImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/policeImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/policeImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weatherTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Jakość powietrza"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/weatherImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/weatherImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weatherImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shopTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sklep"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/shopImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/shopImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shopImageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gminaTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Gmina"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gminaImageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/gminaImageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gminaImageView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

WeatherFragment

```
    public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView airQuality;
    TextView estimateTextView;


    public WeatherFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather, container, false);

        airQuality = (TextView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.airQuality);

        estimateTextView = (TextView) RootView.findViewById(R.id.estimateTextView);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.get("http://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Gajowka%20Modrzewina&state=Mazowieckie&country=Poland&key=M8tKnkEnZWxWDEbfs",new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    int airQualityIndicator = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("current").getJSONObject("pollution").getInt("aqicn");

                    airQuality.setText(String.valueOf(airQualityIndicator));

                    if (airQualityIndicator >= 0 && airQualityIndicator <= 50) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Dobre");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2ECC71"));

                    } else if (airQualityIndicator >= 51 && airQualityIndicator <= 100) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Przeciętne");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFEB3B"));

                    } else if (airQualityIndicator >= 101 && airQualityIndicator <= 150) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Niezdrowe dla wrażliwych grup ludności");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));

                    } else if (airQualityIndicator >= 151 && airQualityIndicator <= 200) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Niezdrowe");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));

                    } else if (airQualityIndicator >= 201 && airQualityIndicator <= 300) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Bardzo niezdrowe");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));

                    } else if (airQualityIndicator > 300) {

                        estimateTextView.setText("Niebezpieczne");
                        airQuality.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5D4037"));

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject response) {

            }
        });

        return RootView;

    }
}
```

fragment_weather.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.przemo.infogmina2.WeatherFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/airQuality"
        android:layout_width="140sp"
        android:layout_height="140sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#2ecc71"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.304" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/estimateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/airQuality"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/airQuality"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/airQuality" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Powietrze w gminie Błędów"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/airQuality"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/airQuality"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/airQuality"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.108" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#F44336"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="151-200"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.916" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#5D4037"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="300+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.916" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#2ECC71"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0-50"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.702" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FF5722"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="101-150"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.702" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#9C27B0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="201-300"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.916" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="55sp"
        android:layout_height="55sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#FFEB3B"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="51-100"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.702" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Dobre"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Niebezpieczne"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.636"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Bardzo niezdrowe"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.583"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

   ...
```

Comment: transaction.addToBackstack(null);.

Comment: A `FragmentTransaction` only handles `Fragment`s. It's not going to remove the `View`s you've put in the container `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike M. said `FragmentTransaction` will not remove any View.So, Just give your fragment layout a white background. It will make layout good.

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:context="com.example.przemo.infogmina2.WeatherFragment">
```